# S3 boto library: How to do a HEAD request on the Key in the bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am new to Boto and using `boto2.29.1` in python.

Added some user metadata using `set_metadata` method

Listing all keys in s3 bucket by using `bucket.list()` method then iterating over keys. But it does not return user metadata as defined in [API reference](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html)

But getting metadata using `bucket.get_key()` returns metadata

API reference says get metadata by doing HEAD request on key. How can i do this?

Comment: I will appreciate if anyone also tell that how to get keys with specific user metadata instead of getting all keys and then filtering keys

Comment: If you are a new customer I would recommend using boto3. ([docs for head_object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object))

Answer (score 8):

In boto3, you can use the [`S3.Client.head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) method to load just the metadata of a single key.

You can also achieve the same thing via the [`load()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.load) method on the `S3.Object`:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')

object.load()  # fetches metadata for the object, but not data.
               # calls client's head_object behind the scene

object.reload() # synonym for load().
                # apparently, we can never have enough duplicated methods.
```

You can access a subset of the associated data by listing keys in a bucket with [S3.Client.list_objects()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) also. In the response to `list_objects`, you'll get things like the storage class, the size, the owner, and the Etag, but you won't get your custom metadata (i.e. `x-amz-meta-*` keys) without `load()`-ing the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Boto does not have direct requests (at least not in `v2`).
The only way to get all the metadata is with the `bucket.get_key()` method.

If you only need the metadata for some of the keys then you can do something like this:

```
for key in bucket.list():
    if want_metadata(key.name):
        key_with_md = bucket.get_key(key.name)
        metadata = key_with_md.get_metadata('smth')
```